# Wait for array to be filled and then render those components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, async-await

I am fetching a list of directories via firebase storage, and then once that has finished, return a list of `Project` components to be rendered, each with the name retrieved before. How do you first wait for the fetching to complete and then return the same number of `Project` components?

This is what I have tried:

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
import "./index.css"
import {hot} from "react-hot-loader"
import Project from "./Project"
import firebase from "./Firebase.js"

function Projects(props){

    // Get refereance to firebase storage
    let storage = firebase.storage();
    // Reference the main projects folder
    let storageRef = storage.ref().child('projects');
    // Store all project names from firebase storage to then return them as Project components
    let projects = []

    // This lists the directories in 'Projects'
    storageRef.listAll().then(res => {
        // For each directory, push the name into the projects array
        res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
            projects.push(folderRef.name)
        })
    }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
    })

    return(
        <div>
            {projects.map(projName => (
                <>
                    <Project project={projName}/>
                </>

            ))}
        </div>
    )




}

export default hot(module)(Projects)
```

However, when `projects` is returned, it is empty as it hasn't waited for the forEach to finish above. Plus, I don't think the return statement within `projects.map()` is working. I have attempted a Promise and Async Await but am not sure how to structure it.

Comment: I suggest to read about `useEffect` and `useState` hooks, please find here the reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#basic-hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to class components, you will need to define your `state` using the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) hook in functional components.

In addition, you should use the `useEffect` hook to handle the carrying out the HTTP request such that it will not be triggered on every re-render. We added an empty array (`[]`) as the second parameter of the `useEffect` hook, such that it will only be run once, as explained on the official React hooks [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

After the responses have been returned, we update the state by calling `setProjects()`.

```
function Projects(props){
  const [ projects, setProjects ] = useState([]);
  let storage = firebase.storage();
  let storageRef = storage.ref().child('projects');

  useEffect(() => {
    const response = []
    storageRef.listAll().then(res => {
    // For each directory, push the name into the projects array
      res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
        response.push(folderRef.name)
      })
      setProjects(response);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
  }, [])

  return(
    <div>
        {projects.length && projects.map((projName, index) => (               
           <Project project={projName} key={index} />
        ))}
    </div>
   )
}

export default hot(module)(Projects)
```

Comment: What happens with `storage` and `storageRef` in each render? Shouldn't be moved inside of `useEffect`? Those references will be recreated on each render I guess. Not sure but maybe worth to move them also inside of `useEffect`, other than that it will show missing dependencies warning message. Or use them simply with `useState`, e.g.: `const [storage, setStorage] = useState(firebase.storage())`.

Comment: @JuniusL. we check `length` as `projects` state is initially an empty array. It will only be populated once the values from firebase has been returned.

Comment: @norbitrial good point! You can move both variables into the useEffects hook. However, I think it is optional to maintain it as part of the component's state since it is only a dependency.

Comment: This is fantastic. Question, where does the key attribute go? I've tried in each Project and and the wrapper div?

Comment: @TavesWalker It should go within `<Project />`.

Comment: @wentjun `<Project project={projName} key={index or projName}/>` still returns the error.

Comment: @TavesWalker what does the `projects` array consist of? I have updated my code to include `key`

Comment: @wentjun Your updated code works. I shouldn't have used fragments `<></>` Thank you.